# Does a UFD imply Euclidean Domain?

Tags: ring-theory

I'm struggling to get my head around the relationship between UFD, PID and Euclidean Domain. I've seen in a theorem in my notes that Euclidean Domain ⇒ PID ⇒ UFD ⇒ ID.
Is it possible for UFD ⇒ ED?

Comment: You may get more responses if you define all the acronyms you have used :)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain  Polynomial ring F[X] is a UFD, but not a PID. Hence not Euclidean domain.

Comment: @Phil polynomial ring in one variable over a field is ED

Comment: @Phil: What is $F$?

Comment: Never mind my previous comment, I think Z[X] as a polynomial ring works, as it is not a PID.

Comment: @Phil this one works

Comment: @Bernard, F would be a field, but look at my previous comment for a correction.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ is UFD, but not a PID and hence also not ED. In general there are PIDs that are not ED for instance [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain) claims that $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is not ED although it is PID. There are also examples in the class of number rings.

Comment: Yes, I have proved a counterexample for this too, I was just wondering if there was a way to use UFD in proving an ED. Since there isn'e a way, could I try using ideals to prove the ED?

Comment: @user22250987 I don't understand. What do you mean by *using ideals to prove the ED*?